# Why does a browser in a different domain not respond at all to "WWW Authenticate : Negotiate" header sent by mod_auth_kerb?

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

I have implemented SSO through mod_auth_kerb in our apache-active directory environment and it works just as expected. However the following knowledge is bugging me :

I requested a Kerberos protected page from two client machines, one user belonged to the Kerberos-setup domain and the other user belonged to some other domain.
I then compared the HTTP packets on the two machines. On both the machines, after the request for the Kerberos protected page is sent,  the server responds with the following HTTP packet :
*HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required 
Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2012 14:25:20 GMT 
Server: Apache WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate 
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Kerberos Login" 
Content-Length: 60 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1*

However, after the above response from the server the client machine's browser belonging to the Kerberos-setup domain responds with a *WWW-Authenticate : Negotiate 'token'*, whereas the other client browser(user belonging to some other domain) does not respond at all.

Now my understanding is, that the client belonging to the other domain should have also responded with its own TGT+Session key token, which the active directory should have rejected. But why this client does not respond at all to the server's *WWW-Authenticate : Negotiate* challenge is beyond my logic.
What is even more confusing is that the server's HTTP response(given above), does not contain any information about the domain it is linked to.

So on what basis is the client browser belonging to the correct domain decide that it has to respond to the server's *WWW-Authenticate : Negotiate* challenge, and on what basis does the client belonging to some other domain decide not to respond to the same ?

Note : Both the client machines have Windows 7 and active directory is a Windows 2008 server.

I am trying to understand mod_auth_kerb's implementation of SSO, and this particular knowledge is key to that.

Comment: Plese correct your question. Do have a problem with a user from a different domain or a user not part of a domain?

Comment: @Michael-O
The user in my problem belongs to a different domain.
I have edited my question for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The module has the option `KrbMethodK5Passwd` turned on. It sends a Basic header to collect you Kerberos credentials. This is pointless for a non-domain client. Disable this option.

There is a hierarchy of strengths of auth mechanisms, the browser is obliged to choose the best. This is: Negotiate, Digest, NTLM, Basic.

Comment: I understand that KrbMethodK5Passwd is turned on and that is why the non-domain browser throws a popup asking login credentials. What i don't understand is why does this non-domain browser not respond with its own TGT+Session key token(like the domain browser) and let the active directory decide whether the token belongs to one of its users. On what basis does the non-domain browser decide that it will not respond to the server's *WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate* ? And on what basis does the domain browser decide that it will respond to the same ?

Comment: Your browser does not respond because there is no domain trust. You have to establish that one first. If that is done, you can perform cross-realm authentication easily. Consult your KDC config docs.

Comment: For chrome, it is required to add authentication whitelists in teh security policy (ADM) in order to allow it to send teh token or negotiate SPNEGO challenges.

Comment: @JalalSordo which Chrome reads the default one on Windows from registry. (Intranet zones)

Comment: @Michael-O : is that a question?

Comment: @JalalSordo No, a statement.